# "System UI isn't responding" error on phone after application update

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asp.net-core

I am dealing with a frustrating problem. I have looked up other solutions to this, and they have not solved it. I am a beginning Android programmer and this is my first application.

I have an application that uses the OpenCore CV software to track motion. In summary, it takes one frame and compares it to the last frame to find the differences, and determine if motion occurs. If there is motion, it times it. Once the motion is "over", it sends the data to a server using an async API call.

Last week, I set up a few of these applications on several phones and they worked great and ran 24/7 for a week straight. This Monday, I used Visual Studio 2019 to download a new version of the code onto the phones (I connected phones to computer, enabled USB debugging, and ran the code). Ever since then, the phones will run for 5-8 hours before a "System UI isn't responding" error, and the chance to either quit the app or wait.

I thought it was an issue with my update, so I reverted the code (since I was using source control). However, the problem persists. This issue is driving me crazy. Log files are not giving me any crash reports whatsoever-the only consistent thing I get around the time of the crash is SFPerfTracer triggers and layers repeating over and over, which I'm pretty sure is just the little pop-up of the error message. And either way, I cannot find what SFPerfTracer *means*.

I have since also restarted all of the phones, cleared cache data, deleted the icon (since some SO thread mentioned too big of an icon can be an issue), and my problems persist.

I am desperate for any help. My project is *huge* so I can't realistically post code-but anything that has helped others

I have since also restarted all of the phones, cleared cache data, deleted the icon (since some SO thread mentioned too big of an icon can be an issue), and my problems persist.

Common SO issues appear to be that there are memory leaks or threading issues. However, I only have the one async call. And tracking the memory usage on Task Manager, the usage stays consistent. And either way, I feel like these would have been issues last week as well. But last week this exact version of this software worked fine....

My project is *huge* so I can't realistically post code. Here is the one section of the logcat file that repeats a fine times in each of the phones that has crashed:

```
09-11 17:41:58.837   625   625 I SFPerfTracer:      triggers: (rate: 9997:128573) (compose: 0:301) (post: 0:79) (render: 0:495) (0:603540 frames) (1:689244)
09-11 17:41:58.837   625   625 D SFPerfTracer:        layers: (6:8) (NavigationBar#0 (0xb2c03000): 0:652) (StatusBar#0 (0xb2c09000): 0:9886) (RoundedOverlay#0 (0xb2c0d000): 0:139) (RoundedOverlay#1 (0xb2c11000): 0:137) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xb2c15000): 0:91)* (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xb2bac000): 0:63)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xb2bd0000): 0:4)* (EmuCvApp.EmuCvApp/md5248cb88610cd50033a1127c8722a4d63.MotionDetectionActivity#0 (0xb2bda000): 0:543) 
09-11 17:42:03.373   625   705 I SFPerfTracer:      triggers: (rate: 0:0) (0 sw vsyncs) (0 skipped) (0:9230 vsyncs) (1:690634)
09-11 17:42:18.053   625   625 I SFPerfTracer:      triggers: (rate: 9997:128574) (compose: 0:301) (post: 0:79) (render: 0:495) (0:603542 frames) (1:689344)
09-11 17:42:18.053   625   625 D SFPerfTracer:        layers: (6:8) (NavigationBar#0 (0xb2c03000): 0:652) (StatusBar#0 (0xb2c09000): 0:9888) (RoundedOverlay#0 (0xb2c0d000): 0:139) (RoundedOverlay#1 (0xb2c11000): 0:137) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xb2c15000): 0:91)* (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xb2bac000): 0:63)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xb2bd0000): 0:4)* (EmuCvApp.EmuCvApp/md5248cb88610cd50033a1127c8722a4d63.MotionDetectionActivity#0 (0xb2bda000): 0:543) 
09-11 17:42:20.766   625   705 I SFPerfTracer:      triggers: (rate: 0:0) (0 sw vsyncs) (0 skipped) (0:9230 vsyncs) (1:690735)
```

I am desperate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have two options, one is to say this question needs to be closed and the other is to provide an answer that may be helpful but it is not granted to be helpful.

As I have seen another user recently claiming that after updating the project he has problems with crashes when using `HttpClient`, I would assume it is a problem in Xamarin.Android. So try to install some older version of VS and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you happen to have a link to that question?

Comment: @WarblerBird it should be this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57890813/202179